# how to make a Carousel as a background I can display things as a side bar menu on it

Tags: html, css

I want to put a side bar menu over the carousel when I hover the principal side bar  using css  I mean to consider the carousel as a background

Comment: Show us what you have right now

Comment: I would use bootstrap, it has built in carousel template, [Bootstrap Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/), check this out

Comment: I already  use bootstrap but my problem that I want to be able to put things above the carousel like a list or something